# pandas df to_csv freezes when using pyinstaller to save the df in the exe directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to save the output dataframe to a csv file while using pyinstaller to create an exe, but my code freezes and generate "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '.\Output.csv' " error. My question is. what wrong using df.to_csv to save the output file in the same exe directory ?

Thanks in adcance

Comment: Are you sure the file Output.csv isn't already open or being used by another program that locks other programs from using it? Usually when you get Permission denied it is one of those two cases or it is password protected.

Comment: Am not sur thats the problem coz when i run the prog on python i got no error. isnt it something about path?

Comment: if you could post a snippet of your code it'd be easier to tell.

Comment: Hi D. Sanders! here it is

Comment: Hi S. Sanders! You're right coz when i run the exe on another computer I got no error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look, if you use Innodb compiler then you will face a problem of permission denied error in the setup. So , I have tried to solve that by using temporary file but It is getting deleted after generation. But if you really want to solve this problem then use xlsxwriter and save it to a specific file location.